# PDF is not converted to jpeg in GhostScript using c#

Tags: ghostscript

I have a PDF file which has 15 pages. When I try convert that pdf to .Jpeg the first four page are getting converted. Ghost script get stuck once it comes to 5th page. I tried it with c# as well as command line. But it doesn't work. Please help.

Please find below example.

C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.52\bin\gswin64c.exe" -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -r300 -o "%temp%/XX%04d.jpg" -f .pdf
it is an argument for GhostScript.

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to help without seeing the input PDF file. Your best bet will be to open a bug report at bugs.ghostscript.com and attach the input file. Also, try a newer version; 9.52 is 3 years old.